# Two ways of printing a SHA-256 hash differ in 1 byte in Python

Tags: python, hex, pycrypto

Consider the snippet:

```
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
text = b'Jeanny'
print('Hash of', text)

hx = SHA256.new(text).hexdigest()
print(hx)

h = SHA256.new(text).digest()
[print('{0:x}'.format(h[i]), end = '' ) for i in range(0,len(h))]
```

It prints:

```
Hash of b'Jeanny'
f51c7dbd56cc25c565f7c7ef951b06121e87e34f2e3bb466e873a2518715fe50
f51c7dbd56cc25c565f7c7ef951b6121e87e34f2e3bb466e873a2518715fe50
```

Why is it that the second printed string of hex digits misses  `0` in position 29?

Comment: As suggested by @Ignacio you need to zero-fill numbers, change the formula in curly bractekt into
`[print('{0:02x}'.format(h[i]), end = '' ) for i in range(0,len(h))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's trying to print "06", but you haven't told it to zero-fill the numbers.